# How to fix side bar when scrolling

Tags: css, sidebar

I am trying to fix the side bar when one will scroll the page like in http://www.myntra.com/maxima?src=tn&nav_id=1027 .

Now, I am able to fix the bar when it appears while scrolling by making its position as fixed. But when the footer appears, as the side bar is fixed, the footer over lapses
 it. How to keep that bar at a distance from the bottom of the page or the footer just as in that link?

```
   if ($(window).scrollTop() > 500) {
        $('#sidebar').css('position', 'fixed');
        $('#sidebar').css('top', '100px');
    } else {
        $('#sidebar').css('top', '0');
        $('#sidebar').css('position', 'relative');

    }

    if($('#footer').offset().top - $('#sidebar').offset().top <=     $('#sidebar').height() + 10)  {

        $('#sidebar').css('bottom', '100px');


    }
```

Comment: I don't understand on what basis the question has been voted down. I am able to fix the side scroll when one will scroll the window (not a big deal for anyone to implement) but I can't fix it till the bottom of the screen as otherwise footer will come over it. It needs to be positioned back to relative. So I was just asking the best possible way to accomplish that. The answer provided to me below has already been implemented by me. And whosoever has voted down the question, please give the answer too if you think the question is too lame.

Answer (score 0):

css

```
position: fixed;
```

or other css

```
position:absolute;
top: 0;
```

or jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $('#scroller').css('top', $(window).scrollTop());
    }
}
);
</script>
```

html

```
<div id="scroller">Some controls</div>
```

css

```
body {
    height: 3000px;
    top: 0;
    position: relative;
}
#scroller {
    position: relative;
    top: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    background: #CCC;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But how will I make sure that when one scrolls to the bottom of the page, sidebar will remain at a distance from the footer. I mean, at some point I have to revert the applied effect. Is distance from footer is the only way to do that?

Comment: change the css `bottom:you px;`

Comment: That will work but then again....distance from header also needs to be taken into consideration. And if I am right, both top and bottom cannot work.

Comment: using `if` and `else if` with jquery

Comment: Hi..I have added the code in the question that I am trying  but bottom is not working. Can you please help me out with the issue?

Comment: If you will look at this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/bH6MH/ , you will see change in css bottom attribute is not getting reflected although top can be changed